# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: cpanel

I uploaded laravel 5.4 in cpanel but I get this error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in
>   /home/lorestantv/MySite.com/public/index.php on line 50

Answer (score 1):

Change PHP version 5.6 or newer.